# Warhol these pictures

Tags: popularity-contest, graphical-output, image-processing

We've all seen the famous painting of Marilyn Monroe created by Andy Warhol.
[image: Marilyn Monroe]

Let's try to replicate that effect with the usual suspects.

Your task is to write a program/programs that do as many as possible of the following tasks:

1. With one image as the input, generate four color palettes from that image and print a 4x4 grid with different "Warhol'd" color variants of that image.
2. With two images as input, generate two color palettes from each image and print a Warhol'd grid of the first image.
3. With four images as input, generate one color palette from each image and print a Warhol'd grid of the first image.

Of course, it would be cheating to hardcode palettes you like the best, **so your program has to determine a set of colors that is both distinct and aesthetically pleasing.** Warhol used five distinct colors in each panel, so five is your goal as well.

Here are some photos that you could use to showcase your program:

[image: Great Wave]
[image: Coral Reef]
[image: Rainbow]
[image: Starry Night]
[image: River]
[image: Brown Bear]
[image: Waterfall]
[image: Mandrill]
[image: Crab Nebula]
[image: American Gothic]
[image: Mona Lisa]
[image: Scream]

Try to achieve a wide range of palette colorings and of course make them as aesthetically pleasing as possible.

This is a popularity contest, so the answer with the most net votes wins.

(Formatting largely copied from [Paint by Numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42217/paint-by-numbers), which was a partial inspiration for this challenge as was [American Gothic in the palette of Mona Lisa: Rearrange the pixels](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/33172/american-gothic-in-the-palette-of-mona-lisa-rearrange-the-pixels))

Comment: [Related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59132/2305) from Mathematica.SE ... and seeing that I have really lost the motivation to do anything but copy the accepted answer, because I won't be able to do better anyway.

Comment: (Oh right, it requires one intermediate manual step... although I suspect that step will be very similar to Paint by Numbers.)

Comment: Martin, What is the intermediate manual step you referred to?

Comment: @DavidCarraher Drawing the red blobs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be an art contest, with [programming serving only a purely functional role](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1962/20260) of implementing artistic effects.

Comment: I like how one picture I generated and one I actually *took* have become our norms.

Comment: Everyone completely misinterpreted this question.  "With one image as the input, generate four color palettes **from that image** and print a 4x4 grid with different "Warhol'd" color variants of that image. " 

It's not just "pick a random color out of a list" such as the first answer, you are meant to programmatically generate a limited palette based on the colors of another image (similar to the two other challenges I linked to)

The interesting element I feel is that picking five random colors from a picture won't yield good results, so how does one determine aesthetics programmatically.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies That would explain why I couldn't find sources for those two when compiling images for Paint by Numbers. :D

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica

```
namedColors = {Red, Green, Blue, Black, White, Gray, Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, Brown, Orange, Pink, Purple};
    myRules = 
      Table[Rule[namedColors[[i]], RandomChoice[namedColors]], {j, 4}, {i,
         Length[namedColors]}];

myImages = {--images here--};

Grid@Table[ColorQuantize[ColorReplace[myImages[[i]], myRules[[j]]],5], 
{i, Length[myImages]}, {j, 4}]
```

[image]